# select from sql database with avg function

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a database as shown below

id , name , var1

and I want to write a sql query like this:

```
select name 
from table 
where last var1 > avg of var1 s of each name
```

Notice that i want to select between names that last var1 is greater than  avrage of var1s of each name

i write this code :

```
select name 
from table 
where var1>(select avg(var1) from table ) limit 0 , 1
```

but this code gets avrage from all var1s and I dont know whether this works or not!

for example we have these data:

```
1 , John , 32
2 , John , 21
3 , Mike , 22
4 , John , 11
5 , Mike , 5
6 , Mike , 45
```

=> for John , we have: 32+21+11 /3 =21.3 , but the last data is 11 , so John shouldnt be chosen
=> for Mike , avrage of var1 is 24 , and last row for Mike is 45 that is greater than the avrage , so Mike should be chosen.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Mysql Database

Comment: I have modified my solution according to your latest edit, please check and let me know if it worked

Comment: thank you , I have about 28Mb of data and it takes too long to response , i'm gono create a smaller db like what i aleady have , and test that on it ...

Comment: I have this data:
john,2
john,5
john,3
mike,3
mike,10
mike,1
and this code:
SELECT y.* FROM
test y
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT name, AVG(val) AS av, MAX(id) AS mx 
   FROM test
   GROUP BY name
) tab
ON y.name = tab.name
AND y.id = tab.mx
AND y.val > tab.av


but I get nothing!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT y.* FROM
your_table y
JOIN
(
   SELECT name, AVG(var1) AS av, MAX(id) AS mx 
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY name
) tab
ON y.name = tab.name
AND y.id = tab.mx
AND y.var1 > tab.av
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0575/1)

[EDIT]:
Based on your latest requirement, what you want to accomplish is `LIMIT N within group`, which can be done with the following query:

```
SET @N := 2;
SELECT * FROM 
( 
   SELECT (@rownumber:= @rownumber + 1) AS rn, yt.*
   FROM your_table yt,(SELECT @rownumber:= 0) nums
   ORDER BY name, id 
 ) k
 JOIN
 (
    SELECT t.name, MAX(rn) AS MaxRN FROM
    ( 
      SELECT (@rownumber:= @rownumber + 1) AS rn, yt.*
      FROM your_table yt,(SELECT @rownumber:= 0) nums
      ORDER BY name, id 
     ) t
     GROUP BY name
 ) l
 ON k.rn <= l.MaxRN AND k.rn > l.MaxRN - @N
```

Here @N variable holds number of records we want to select within each group
Check the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0575/19)

Now in an outer query we can take the avg of the resultset returned by above.

Let me know if you could accomplish what you wanted with my inputs.

Comment: Thanks , it works , but i have another question, what should I do if i want to get that avrage from n recent data ?

Comment: Ok it's getting interesting! In ant other DB it would have been quite easy to using Row_Number function, but in MySQL we need to go extra mile to accomplish your latest requirement. I will try it.

Comment: Thank you , I'm waiting...
The next and maybe the last issue is : gettin n last row that greater than avg of m rows :)

Comment: Your questions are interesting. Why don't you put them in another page so that others can also benefit from it and other members can also come up with solutions. Please share with me the link of the query page.

Comment: Thanks , but how can i do that? you mean i should open a new topic?

Comment: Yes, if that's not very difficult.

Comment: Isn't it against the site's rule?

Comment: it seems that your edited code doesn't work , let me explain again , i want to find any row in n last rows that greater than avrage of m last rows

Comment: Or this is also good :
get any name of row that var1 of that row greater than avrage of maximom n rows back from that row

Comment: Is it giving some error, or you mean logically it's not giving correct result?

Comment: no , there is no error , just return nothing, I asked my question again here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150304/how-to-get-upper-trend-with-avg-mysql