# how to get upper trend with avg mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql Database like below:
id , name , col1

and i want to find all rows that: value of col1 of the row is greater than avrage of maximom 5 rows past 
for example if I have 50 rows , and if the row #20 has gotten , the avrage of value of col1 of  rows #20,#19,#18,#17,#16 should be less than the value of col1 of row #20 , and so on...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or and sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. Also, make it clear whether or not id is numbered sequentially (with no gaps)

Comment: Can you explain more? or do have any codes?

Comment: No. I'm going to leave it at that for now. Come back if you have a specific question that cannot be answered by googling.

Comment: I didn't find my answer by googling , thats why i'am here!!

Comment: Ok I am looking into it

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want here is running average of past M records starting from current record and we need to select the current record if current record's column value is greater than the running average.

Here is my attempt to it:

```
SET @M := 2;

SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT (@rownumber:= @rownumber + 1) AS rn, yt.*
  FROM your_table yt,(SELECT @rownumber:= 0) nums
  ORDER BY name, id
) a
WHERE a.var1 > 
(
    SELECT avg(b.var1)
    FROM
    (
      SELECT (@rownumber:= @rownumber + 1) AS rn, yt.*
      FROM your_table yt,(SELECT @rownumber:= 0) nums
      ORDER BY name, id
    ) b
    WHERE b.rn > a.rn - @M AND b.rn <= a.rn 
)
```

@M is count of past records to be considered for finding running average.

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0575/25)

[EDIT]:

Here is another solution which according to me should be more efficient than correlated query.

```
SET @M := 2;

 SELECT a.* FROM
 ( 
  SELECT (@rownumber:= @rownumber + 1) AS rn, yt.*
      FROM your_table yt,(SELECT @rownumber:= 0) nums
      ORDER BY name, id
 ) a
 JOIN 
 (
    SELECT b.name, b.rn, AVG(c.var1) AS av
    FROM
    (
      SELECT (@rownumber1:= @rownumber1 + 1) AS rn, yt.*
      FROM your_table yt,(SELECT @rownumber1:= 0) nums
      ORDER BY name, id
    ) b
    JOIN
    (
      SELECT (@rownumber2:= @rownumber2 + 1) AS rn, yt.*
      FROM your_table yt,(SELECT @rownumber2:= 0) nums
      ORDER BY name, id
    ) c
    ON b.name = c.name
    AND c.rn > (b.rn - @M) AND c.rn <= b.rn
    GROUP BY b.name,b.rn
 ) runningavg 
 ON a.name = runningavg.name
 AND a.rn = runningavg.rn
 AND a.var1 > runningavg.av
```

Here I have used simple `inner join` to calculate running average and again with inner join have selected rows which have column value greater than average.

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0575/60)

Let me know did it prove to be efficient.

Comment: Thank you , it works on SQL FIDDLE , but it's very slow and i'm waiting to get response for about 10 minutes and still running.... :(

Comment: Yes this query is not efficient which usually this correlated queries be, more often than not. I will try to give you a efficient solution.

Comment: Thank you alot , but it still takes too long :( , I think it's better to code php .

Comment: that's a sorry state of affairs. no problem, can you try creating index on (name,id) columns. It would improve the efficiency.